# Jquery Validator Not Running

Tags: jquery, validation

I am by no means an expert but I have done this before and for some reason there is an issue with my form not validating this time.

I did this on another page and it worked fine so I just cut pasted it to another section and did minor changes and now it stopped working.

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hsSQY/) and any hints would be welcomed.

Html:

```
<form action="" id="ad_brochure_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" language="JavaScript" name="FrontPage_Form2">
    <fieldset>
        <legend style="margin-left:8em;" class="big">Contact Information</legend>
        <p id="required">All Fields Are Required</p>

        <label>First Name</label><input placeholder=" Jane or John" id="firstname" name="firstName" size="25" style="border: 1px solid #FFFFFF; width: 235px;" tabindex="1" type="text" />                                  
        <label>Last Name</label><input placeholder=" Doe" id="lastname" name="lastName" size="25" style="border: 1px solid #FFFFFF; width: 235px;" tabindex="1" type="text" />                                    
        <label>Title</label><input placeholder="RN" id="firsttitle" maxlength="100" name="title" size="50" style="border: 1px solid #FFFFFF; width: 235px;" tabindex="2" type="text" />                                     
        <label>Email</label><input placeholder=" example@example.com" id="firstemail" maxlength="100" name="email" size="50" style="border: 1px solid #FFFFFF; width: 235px;" tabindex="2" type="text" />                                 
        <label>Work Phone</label><input placeholder=" 000-0000" id="firstphone" maxlength="100" name="phone" size="50" style="border: 1px solid #FFFFFF; width: 102px;" tabindex="3" type="text"/>

     </fieldset>
     <fieldset>
         <legend style=" margin-left:12em;">Facility Information</legend>

         <label>Facility Name</label><input maxlength="100" id="firstfacility" placeholder=" NIFA" name="facility" size="50" style="border: 1px solid #FFFFFF; width: 232px;" tabindex="4" type="text" />                               
         <label>Address</label><input maxlength="100" id="firstaddress" placeholder=" 555 Example St." name="address" size="50" style="border: 1px solid #FFFFFF; width: 232px;" tabindex="4" type="text" />                                
         <label>City</label><input placeholder=" City" id="firstcity" name="city" size="20" style="border: 1px solid #FFFFFF; width: 232px;" tabindex="5" type="text" />                                    
         <label>State</label><input placeholder=" State" id="firststate" name="state" size="20" style="border: 1px solid #FFFFFF; width: 232px;" tabindex="5" type="text" />                        
         <label>Zip</label><input placeholder=" 00000" id="firstzip" name="zip" style="border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;" tabindex="7" type="text" />

     </fieldset>
     <input id="brochure_submit" name="Submit" tabindex="8" type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
 </form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("test");

    $('#ad_brochure_form >form').validate({
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        },
        errorElement: "em",
        rules: {
            firstname: {required: true},
            lastname: {required: true},
            firsttitle: {required: true},
            firstphone: {required: true,
            firstfacility: {required: true},
            firstaddress: {required: true},
            firstcity: {required: true},
            firststate: {required: true},
            firstzip: {required: true},
            firstemail: {required: true, email: true}
        },
        messages: {
            firstname: {required: "Please enter your first name<br />"},
            lastname: { required: "Please enter your first name<br />"},
            firstaddress: {required: "Please enter your street address<br />"},
            firstcity: {required: "Please enter the city in which the facility is <br />"},
            firststate: {required: "Please enter the state"},
            firstfacility: {required: "Please enter a facility name<br />" },
            firstzip: { required: "Please enter the zipcode of the facility<br />"},
            firstemail: {email: "Please enter a valid email<br />",required: "A valid email is required<br />"},
            firstphone: {required: "Please enter a valid number<br />"}
        },
        success: function (element) {
            element.remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: where is your jquery-validator js related declaration in code?

Comment: It's there in my real code I just couldn't figure out how to get it on JSFiddle.

Comment: just added it to the code here and not the fiddle.

Comment: Are you receiving any errors in the developer console?

Comment: Is there a chance of confliction of js files with other js files? please check it...

Comment: No errors in the console. The only thing odd is I did another console.log("end test") after the Jquery Validator call and it didn't show in the console.

Comment: There are no other JS files for this page.

Comment: Here is the actual page so if you could look over the source. http://www.rnfa.org/NewsletterArchives/2013-February/jump1_Implementing_an_RNFA_Team.html